# How do you create a floating variable in Python?

Tags: python, loops, variables, python-requests, floating

Hi I'm trying to do my computer science course work, which is there to test my abilities (the one I chose was a Dice game. We are allowed to use recourses so I came here, and I need help as I have to create a scoring system but I need it to change with the round numbers so it can add the variables to get a final score. Any help would be great! I have attached my code below:

```
import time
import random
def totalScore(n,s):

 file = open("total.txt", "a")
 file.write("name: " + n + ", total: " + str(s) + "\n")
 file.close()
 return

def login():
    while True:
        print("")
        username = input('What is your username? ')
        password = input('What is your password? ')
        if username not in ('User1', 'User2'):
            print("")
            print('Incorrect username, try again')
        if password != 'password':
            print("")
            print('Incorrect password, try again')
            continue
        print("")
        print(f'Welcome, {username} you have been successfully logged in.')
        break
user1 = login()
user2 = login()
print("")
print("")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("               Rules")
print("               -----")
time.sleep(1)
print("• The points rolled on each player’s dice are added to their score.")
time.sleep(2)
print("• If the final total is an even number, an additional 10 points are added to their score.")
time.sleep(2)
print("• If the final total is an odd number, 5 points are subtracted from their score.")
time.sleep(2)
print("• If they roll a double, they get to roll one extra die and get the number of points rolled added to their score.")
time.sleep(2)
print("• The score of a player cannot go below 0 at any point.")
time.sleep(2)
print("• The person with the highest score at the end of the 5 rounds wins.")
time.sleep(2)
print("• If both players have the same score at the end of the 5 rounds, they each roll 1 die and whoever gets the highest score wins (this repeats until someone wins).")
time.sleep(2)
print("")
print("")

round_number = 0
msg = "Press Enter to Start The Round:\n\n"
while True:
    if input(msg).lower() != '':
        continue

    round_number += 1
    print(f"Round Number {round_number}\n")

    print("User1 goes first : ")
    roll_number = 0
    dice3 = 0
    print("")
    msg = "Press Enter to Roll The Dice: \n\n"
    while True:
        if input(msg).lower() != '':
           continue

        roll_number = 1
        dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(f"1> You got a {dice1}\n")
        input ("Press Enter to Roll Again!")
        roll_number = 2
        dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(f"2> You got a {dice2}\n")
        if roll_number == 2:
            break
    print("You have used both of your rolls")
    total = dice1 + dice2
    print("your total for this round is " + str(total) + ".")

    if dice1 == dice2:
        input ("Lucky!, you get an additional roll : ")
        roll_number = 3
        dice3 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(f"Bonus Role> You got a {dice3}\n")
        total = total + dice3
        print("your final total for this round is " + str(total) + ".")

    print("User2 its your turn now : ")
    roll_number = 0
    dice3 = 0
    print("")
    msg = "Press Enter to Roll The Dice: \n\n"
    while True:
        if input(msg).lower() != '':
           continue

        roll_number = 1
        dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(f"1> You got a {dice1}\n")
        input ("Press Enter to Roll Again!")
        roll_number = 2
        dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(f"2> You got a {dice2}\n")
        if roll_number == 2:
            break
    print("You have used both of your rolls")
    total = dice1 + dice2
    print("your total for this round is " + str(total) + ".")

    if dice1 == dice2:
        input ("Lucky!, you get an additional roll : ")
        roll_number = 3
        dice3 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(f"Bonus Role> You got a {dice3}\n")
        total = total + dice3
        print("your final total for this round is " + str(total) + ".")

    msg = "Press Enter to Start a new round! \n"
    round_number
    if round_number == 5:
        break
print("All the rounds are complete")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [mcve] so we can help you focus in on your problem and solve it. You can edit your question to show just the relevant parts of your codr

Comment: What isn't working? What specifically are you stuck with?

Comment: @Sayse Hi , thanks for showing interest I'm trying to add a scoring system where I could get a variable called score to loop and add up all the totals at the end. Unfortunately when I try this the best that happens is the previous number gets printed out.

Comment: @user12303290 Please edit your question and exaplain once again what is the problem with the shared code above. In addition, read the following to minimize the code part in your question, as it is not readable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, you must create two scores (score1 and score2) and use a temp variable that calculate score of current round and current player, if this temp var is negative, you must reset to 0, after that you can accumulate this temp score with player score (score1 or score2)

Answer (score 0):

you have to write readable code with some functions, comments, etc...
for your scoring, I made comments in this code below to help you complete this game, but before add scoring, take your time to read this code.

```py
import random

def calculate_score(score, total):
    """ this function return updated score """
    # add total to score
    # if total is even add 10 points to score
    # if total is odd substract 5 points to score
    # if score is positive return score
    # else return 0
    return 0

def read_enter(msg="Press Enter"):
    """ this function block user and force him to press enter"""
    while input(msg).lower() != '':
       continue

def roll_dice(msg=""):
    """ this function return a random number dice"""
    dice = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(msg, end="")
    print(f"> You got a {dice}\n")
    return dice

def player_turn(message="It's your turn : ", score=0):
    """ this function is a player turn, that return the updated score """
    print(message,"\n")
    msg = "Press Enter to Roll The Dice: \n\n"

    read_enter(msg)
    dice1 = roll_dice("1")
    read_enter("Press Enter to Roll Again!")
    dice2 = roll_dice("2")

    print("You have used both of your rolls")
    total = dice1 + dice2
    print("your total for this round is " + str(total) + ".")
    # to update score
    updated_score = calculate_score(score, total)
    dice3 = 0
    if dice1 == dice2:
        input("Lucky!, you get an additional roll : ")
        dice3 = roll_dice("Bonus Role")
        total = total + dice3
        print("your final total for this round is " + str(total) + ".")
    # return the updated score added with dice3
    return updated_score + dice3

def dice_game():
    """ the main function game """
    msg = "Press Enter to Start The Round:\n\n"
    score_user1 = score_user2 = 0
    for round_number in range(5):
        read_enter(msg)
        print("Round Number ", (round_number+1), "\n")
        # you can print scores to keep players updated with theirs scores
        score_user1 = player_turn("User1 goes first : ", score_user1)
        score_user2 = player_turn("User2 its your turn now : ", score_user2)

        msg = "Press Enter to Start a new round! \n"
    print("All the rounds are complete")
    # while both players have the same score
        # roll 1 die for player 1 and update score
        # roll 1 die for player 2 and update score
        # if they have same die number
            # continue
        # else break
    # annonce the winner
    pass

def main():
    dice_game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```